# GUID PK + INT IDENTITY Clustered Index + Merge Replication + Foreign Keys

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with GUID PKs, and I understand the performance benefit from adding an `INT IDENTITY` column (e.g. `ClusterID`) and then creating a clustered index on it.

And for joins there would be a performance benefit from using the `ClusterID` column as the foreign key. Especially in a parent/child situation where the child table could then have a clustered index on the parent `ClusterID`.

However in a merge replication scenario that's not possible because the `ClusterID` column will not necessarily be unique.

So I'm wondering how best to gain the performance benefits in this situation.

For example:

TableA

- ID guid (primary key)
- ClusterID int identity (clustered index)`

TableB

- ID guid (primary key)
- TableAID guid (foreign key to TableA)
- TableAClusterID int (clustered index)`

I guess I would use a trigger to keep `TableAClusterID` up-to-date.

Then a query such as

```
select * 
from TableB B 
where B.TableAClusterID = @TableAClusterId
```

would benefit from increased performance.

Is this how its done?

Comment: What performance benefit are you talking about? Insert performance? fragmentation?

Comment: Why would ClusterID not be unique in a Merge Replication scenario?  If you're using automatic identity range management then that guarantees IDs will be unique.

Comment: @Ben - I can't find one article that summarises it although http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/ comes close, but from what I've read all performance will generally improve with a clustered index, even if the column isn't used data.

Comment: @marc_s is probably in a better position to answer this, as hes answered many questions about this.

Comment: @Brandon - good point - I was thinking to try and keep things simple on the replication front, and keep any complexity local.

Comment: If you aren't sure exactly what benefit you are expecting, how will you know if you have got it? My advice is don't do this just because you heard somewhere it was a good idea.... for insert performance you really just need the index to be in the order inserted. identity does that, but so does timestamp. Again, don't do this unless you are sure you know what you expect to gain. Instead, look at the query plan for your slow-performing queries, and devise indexes from that.

Answer (score -1):

For very heavy INSERTS GUID will perform better than `INT IDENTITY` because you won't have a contention on it. There are some technics to fix it, but it still can be a problem. In all other cases `INT/BIGINT` perform much better. they are unique in very big range and have size 2-4 size smaller than GUID. If you multiply these extra 12 bytes on number of rows using GUIDs and then multiply on number of non clustered indexes built on your Clustered GUID Index you'll see %% of your database size used by that junk. I assume, the same percentage drop you have in your performance, if not more. Size always matters.